# How to properly use arrows for ES6 React class functions?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, brunch, es6-class

I have a react component that works without arrow functions (commented out below), but I would love being able to use arrow functions instead of binding each function by hand.

This (the not commented out part) is what I tried:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class CowClicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    }
    // this.onCowClick = this.onCowClick.bind(this) 
    // that makes it work if I use a normal function instead of a fat arrow one for onCowClick
  }

  // alternative that works: onCowClick(evt) {...}
  onCowClick = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Clicks: {this.state.clicks}</div>
        <img
          src="http://s3.bypaulshen.com/buildwithreact/cow.png"
          onClick={this.onCowClick}
          className="cow"
          />
        <p>Click the cow</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**How can I enable the use of arrow functions in my project ?**

[This link](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/)
 seems to be part of the solution, but as a front-end newbie I fail to know how to apply it.

Also, as a side question, how do you know what is wrong in a jsx file ? What are good tools to troubleshoot react code ? I picked brunch as a build system because it seemed the simplest to get started with front-end, and the only error it gives me is `Compiling of app/components/CowClicker.jsx failed.`

---

For more context :

- my app is set up using `brunch new -s react`, which puts a react app skeleton in place
- I'm using vscode as a text editor if you have any linting / compilation error spotting extensions to recommend, I would definitely appreciate
- My build config (I build with brunch) looks like this (it's the default one with the 'react' skeleton of brunch) :

.

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/,
        'app.js': /^app/
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
  }
};
```

Comment: The line you commented out is correct btw - What line is the error? I don't quite understand your question

Comment: `onCowClick = (evt) => {` in a class is an experimental syntax proposal, if you're using Babel you'll need to explicitly enable it.

Comment: *"that makes it work if I use a normal function instead of a fat arrow one"* You cannot bind the `this` value of arrow functions.

Comment: Another alternative would be `::onCowClick` using https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/

Comment: @zinc How can I know on what line my error is ? I'm very interested in knowing that

Comment: How are you compiling it? What's your build pipeline looking like?

Comment: @zinc I included my build config in the question

Comment: Note that using function properties is convenient, but they're created per-instance. This often doesn't matter, e.g., components that appear on the page once, but if the component has hundreds of instances, it may be undesirable.

Comment: @loganfsmyth How can I enable that ? I put a link in my question that tells me to add `"optional": ["es7.classProperties"]` in a config, but I have no idea in what config file

Comment: @FelixKling I actually meant I'm trying to use fat arrows instead of binding manually. I edited the question to try to make that clearer

Comment: @DaveNewton What is the alternative in my case ? Where can I learn about that ?

Comment: @n-marshall You are looking for https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: @n-marshall Not sure what you're asking. In any case you need the stage-n preset that include class properties. I forget which one it's in, but each stage documents what's included.